# User is not able to view, edit, or add new records

Tags: error

There are 4 Users that can view my form but can not add, edit a record. When user clicks "New Item" It appears that there
 are no spaces for input. The same happens with the "edit" button.

While other users can user my site.

I checked the permissions and it appeared they have the same role as the engineers in Buffalo. I deleted their access and tried granting it again but still did not work.

Any one know why and what can I do..

Thank you
[image]

Comment: infopath form? or?

Comment: I created it using sharepoint designer 2013, but my other colleuges can use it fine, but a few cant. that's why I am confused

Comment: Do those users have contribute rights to the list the form is posting?

Comment: Can you ask those users to try from a different computer? Or a different browser?

Comment: Yes the permission level is "Edit".... Also in a different browser they still had the issue .

Comment: It like they can see the form if I remove my custom form that I created in sharepoint designer 2013. why is that

Comment: Does anyone have a clue?